# Windows 8 can't stop a service

Tags: windows-8

I bought a computer and it has a McAfee thing and it uses 20% of my CPU. I tried to stop it, but get "access is denied". I've tried using process hacker but it doesn't help. Still get access is denied. Please help me if you can. Any ideas are welcome. This is really ruining my computers performance.

Comment: Please do not swear and shout. Did you try uninstalling the software instead of just stopping it?

Comment: Uninstall it from Programs and Features.

Comment: i cant uninstall it. It doesn't show anywhere. It just is there and if i try to terminate with process hacker but it says the same thing over and over again.(and sorry for swearing and shouting. i'm just so frustrated about that program that doesn't have any use for me at all.)

Comment: Just tried the MacAfee remover thing, but i don't think it will work taken the fact that i didn't install it myself. We'll see. And the exact name is "McAfee Service Controller".

Comment: Use Autoruns to disable the service or process from starting.  That will allow you to delete the file itself

Comment: in the uninstall programs, it doesn't show anything related to MacAfee. thats the biggest problem i have on that basis.i was able to disable all the other servies escept the service controller which is the one using all the CPU percentages(not sure if that is how it is spelled).

Comment: it doesn't give me the permission to disable it in any kind.

Answer (score 0):

McAfee offers the [McAfee Consumer Product Removal tool](https://service.mcafee.com/faqdocument.aspx?id=TS101331) to help you uninstall McAfee products. Use it when the product isn’t visible in Windows’ “Programs and Features” control panel.

Comment: thanks! I just started, and would like to see if it works but it's taking so long :D. 30 minutes in and still not completed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i used the uninstaller but it jammed on something for hours so i just closed it. Then checked and it's running but using 0% of CPU. Not what i was expecting but works for me. Thanks guys. Don't know how i didn't think of that uninstaller thing.